# how to use qx.data.store.Json

Tags: json, qooxdoo

I would like to know how to use the qx.data.store.Json-Store exactly.
In my case I have f.e. this methods implemented in a webservice:

- getUser
- addUser
- deleteUser
- addDocument
- getDocument
- deleteDocument

My question now is: Do I have to create a store (extend from qx.data.store.Json) and implement this methods
like:

```
var store = new myapp.store.MyJsonStore(url);
var user = store.getUser("testuser");
```

or should I use the original qx.data.store.Json for all the methods above?
like:

```
var store = new qx.data.store.Json("http://localhost:1234/users/testuser");
var user = store.getModel();
```

In the second case I would have to create the store for each request again and make it f.e. async.

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`qx.data.store.Json`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.Json) is read-only store implementation. It just sets its *model* property, which value is converted from JSON (with [`qx.data.marshal.Json`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.marshal.Json)) retrieved from the URL passed to its constructor. In general in Qooxdoo data-layer design all connections are bidirectional.

[image: Qooxdoo data layer]

It's possible to make read-write JSON store through subclassing `qx.data.store.Json`. Its *model* is normal Qooxdoo data object. You can bind to it, you can listen to its changes (the store creates model with bubbling changes) and so on.

Here goes example for list controller, which model is [`qx.data.Array`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.Array). Its *change* event has type (add, remove and others). So you can make a corresponding request when the model has changed. Backend is CherryPy application for dummy RPC. Note that it is a demo code, which doesn't dispose request objects, listens for fail events, and other things you should do in a real code.

*JsonStore.js*

```
qx.Class.define('adhoc.JsonStore', {

  extend : qx.data.store.Json,

  construct : function(baseUrl, delegate)
  {
    this.base(arguments, baseUrl + '/list', delegate);

    this._baseUrl = baseUrl;

    // can't refine model property to set apply method because
    // it has not init value
    this.addListener('changeModel', this._onChangeModel, this);
  },

  members : {

    _baseUrl : null,


    _create : function(entry)
    {
      var request = new qx.io.request.Xhr(this._baseUrl + '/create');
      request.setAccept('application/json');
      request.setParser('json');
      request.setRequestData(qx.util.Serializer.toNativeObject(entry));
      request.addListener('success', this.reload, this);
      request.send();
    },

    _remove : function(entry)
    {
      var request = new qx.io.request.Xhr(this._baseUrl + '/remove');
      request.setAccept('application/json');
      request.setParser('json');
      request.setRequestData({'id': entry.getId()});
      request.send();      
    },

    _onChagneModelDataArray : function(event)
    {
      var change = event.getData();
      if(change.type == 'add')
      {
        this._create(change.added[0]);
      }
      else if(change.type == 'remove')
      {
        this._remove(change.removed[0]);
      }
    },

    _onChangeModel : function(event)
    {
      var model = event.getData();
      model.addListener('change', this._onChagneModelDataArray, this);
    }

  }

});
```

*Application.js*

```
qx.Class.define('adhoc.Application', {

  extend : qx.application.Standalone,

  members : {

    main : function()
    {
      this.base(arguments);

      if(qx.core.Environment.get('qx.debug'))
      {
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        qx.log.appender.Console;
      }


      var list = new qx.ui.form.List();
      list.setWidth(120);

      var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(null, list);
      controller.setLabelPath('name');
      controller.setLabelOptions({'converter': function(value, model) 
      {
        return model.getId() + ':' + value;
      }});

      var store = new adhoc.JsonStore('/document');
      store.bind('model', controller, 'model');


      var create = new qx.ui.form.Button('Create');
      create.addListener('execute', function()
      {
        var name = window.prompt('Enter document name');
        if(name)
        {
          controller.getModel().push(qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel({
            'id'   : null,
            'name' : name
          }));
        }
      });

      var remove = new qx.ui.form.Button('Remove');
      controller.bind('selection[0]', remove, 'enabled',{'converter':Boolean});
      remove.addListener('execute', function()
      {
        var confirmed = window.confirm('Remove selected document?');
        if(confirmed)
        {
          controller.getModel().remove(controller.getSelection().getItem(0));
        }
      });


      var root = this.getRoot();
      root.add(create, {'left': 10, 'top': 10});
      root.add(remove, {'left': 70, 'top': 10});
      root.add(list,   {'left': 10, 'top': 40});
    }

  }

});
```

*app.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/static' : {
    'tools.staticdir.on'  : True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir' : os.path.join(path, 'qxjsonstore')
  }  
}


class Document:

  _store = None


  def __init__(self):
    self._store = {
      1 : {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'},
      2 : {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'},
      3 : {'id': 3, 'name': 'baz'},
      4 : {'id': 4, 'name': 'qux'},
    }

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def list(self):
    return self._store.values()

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def create(self, **kwargs):
    id = max(self._store.keys()) + 1
    self._store[id] = {'id': id, 'name': kwargs['name']}
    return id

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def remove(self, id):
    del self._store[int(id)]


class App:

  document = None


  def __init__(self):
    self.document = Document()

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Demo is built on qx.js from the framework's build-all job. 
             Do not use it in real application because it includes all
             Qooxdoo classes.
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var qx = {};
          qx.$$environment = {"qx.application": "adhoc.Application"};
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/qx.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body></body>
      </html>
    '''


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Here's [runnable snippet](http://runnable.com/VLU5s31exkB_kd60) for the demo. Also in case of advanced binding to `qx.data.Array` beware of [bug#8127](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8127) which the team doesn't hurry to fix. User-code fix [is possible](https://code.google.com/p/qooxdoo-website-skeleton/source/browse/source/class/website/Fix.js?repo=frontend) though.

Answer (score 0):

`qx.data.store.Json` only GETs data from the server. I don't see how you can implement `addUser` or `deleteUser` using `qx.data.store.Json` - there's no way to set request data on the Xhr the store uses internally. From the qooxdoo manual: "The main purpose of the store components is to load data from a source and convert that data into a model." Nothing about writing back to the server there - in fact, the only explicitly read+write store is the offline store - which makes use of local storage.

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use `qx.io.rest.Resource` to fetch, add and delete (and probably also update) users and documents on the server. With this, you can map combinations of URLs and http verbs to server-side operations on users and documents. This also lets you set data to send along for operations like add and update. You can get the data returned by the async actions called on the resource by listening for the `success` event on the resource itself - whatever data there is in the response it will be in the event's `data` property.

You can then automatically convert the JSON contained in the event to qooxdoo objects via `qx.data.marshal.Json`, then set the resulting model into a controller's model property. It will create the same type of classes as the stores in `qx.data.store`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think you are not right. It is possible to add data to the Xhr-Object through the delegate but it seems to be a little bit to complicated for a simple Post/Put/Delete. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481647/how-to-bind-a-tree-to-a-model-in-qooxdoo-and-what-format-the-that-should-have

Comment: Right - you could achieve what you want using `.reload()`/`.setUrl()` in combination with a delegate. But I agree it isn't nice - the delegate would need to be aware of what is going on when it is called.